# Binding child input :value to the parent prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, binding, vuejs3

I try to bind child input value to the parent value. I pass value `searchText` from a Parent component to a Child component as prop `:valueProp`.  There I assign it to property `value: this.valueProp` and bind input:

`<input type="text" :value="value" @input="$emit('changeInput', $event.target.value)" />`

The problem is that input doesn't work with such setup, nothing displays in input, but parent `searchText` and `valueProp` in child update only with the last typed letter; `value` in child doesn't update at all, though it is set to equal to `searchText`.

If I remove `:value="value"` in input, all will work fine, but `value` in child doesn't get updated along with parent's `searchText`.

I know that in such cases it's better to use `v-model`, but I want to figure out the reason behind such behavior in that case.

I can't understand why it works in such way and `value` in child component doesn't update with parent's `searchText`. Can you please explain why it behaves in that way?

Link to Sanbox: [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-rgb-hgc4sf?file=/src/components/Child.vue)

Parent:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <Child :valueProp="searchText" @changeInput="changeInput" />
      <p>parent {{ searchText }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Child from "./Child.vue";

export default {
  name: "Parent",
  components: { Child },
  data() {
    return {
      searchText: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeInput(data) {
      console.log(data);
      this.searchText = data;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Child:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" :value="value" @input="$emit('changeInput', $event.target.value)" />
    <p>value: {{ value }}</p>
    <p>child: {{ valueProp }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  emits: ["changeInput"],
  data() {
    return {
      value: this.valueProp,
    };
  },
  props: {
    valueProp: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the `value` in your `Child` component only once by instantiating.

In the `data()` you set the initial value of your data properties:

```
data() {
    return {
      value: this.valueProp,
    };
},
```

Since you don't use `v-model`, the `value` will never be updated.

You have the following options to fix it:

1. The best one is to use `v-model` with `value` in the `Child.vue`

---

```
 <input
      type="text"
      v-model="value"
```

2. update `value` using watcher

---

```
 watch: {
    valueProp(newValue) {
        this.value = newValue;
    }
  },
```

3. use a computed property for `value` instead of data property

---

```
computed: {
    value() {return this.valueProp;}
}
```

---

*Respect for creating the sandbox!*

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the local value every time the value changes

```js
data() {
  return {
    value: this.valueProp, // Don't do this
  };
},
```

Bind directly to the prop:

```html
<input ... :value="valueProp" ... />
```